# systemctl list-unit-files does not show my service

Tags: systemd, services

When I execute `systemctl list-unit-files`  does not show my service command it does not show my service (called example). What can be the reason of that?

init.d file location:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/example
```

service files:

```
/run/systemd/generator.late/example.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/runlevel5.target.wants/example.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/runlevel4.target.wants/example.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/runlevel3.target.wants/example.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/runlevel2.target.wants/example.service
```

.Service file:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/rc.d/init.d/example
Description=SYSV: Application Suite
Before=runlevel2.target
Before=runlevel3.target
Before=runlevel4.target
Before=runlevel5.target
After=network-online.target
After=network.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/example start
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `systemctl list-unit` instead, it will show all loaded (active) units, including those generated.

The `list-unit-files` only works for the actual installed unit files. To debug the generated ones looking at the `/run` directory is I guess fine. Alternatively you can use `systemctl show example.service` to see the in-memory properties, which has some overlap with the unit files.

BTW, for a given unit name, you can use `systemctl is-enabled <name> -l` to see if it is „generated“, or where it is statically installed.