# systemctl does not see service apt install on Kubuntu 21.04 installed itself

Tags: apt, kubuntu, 21.04

Hi my problem is neatly summarised by this:

```
mike@gamer:~$ sudo apt install xvfb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
xvfb is already the newest version (2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1.1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

mike@gamer:~$ sudo systemctl status xvfb
Unit xvfb.service could not be found.

mike@gamer:~$ sudo apt install x11vnc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
x11vnc is already the newest version (0.9.16-7).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

mike@gamer:~$ sudo systemctl status x11vnc
Unit x11vnc.service could not be found.
mike@gamer:~$
```

To be clear, systemctl can't see some of the services I have installed in Kubuntu 21.04 with apt. It's not the case that it can't see anything I've installed. I installed xrdp no problem. All I am really trying to do is be able to rdp into my Kubuntu box but I need some version of vnc to be running or xvfb or something (to act as a vnc bridge for rdp). I was really looking forward to "native" Wayland support (but whether you've got a true Wayland compositor or not it should be handled b the X11Wayland library or whatever it's called) but I'm willing to forego all that just to be able to access my desktop and run GUI apps from a remote machine whether it be a Linux or Win 10 or Apple macOS or Android phone or iOS phone or whatever. I want to run this headless as a server.

I truly hope I'm missing the obvious. There are **loads** of related posts online but to be honest nearly all of them are rubbish or pre-date 21.04 or flat out contradict each other.

Thanks very much in advance for any information which will resolve this quickly. It seems to me that the minimum 21.04 should be able to do is let you interact with and use the servicess you install.

The only apparently related post [1]: [systemctl list-unit-files does not show my service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195595/systemctl-list-unit-files-does-not-show-my-service) doesn't really address the problem

Comment: *packages* and *services* are not synonymous - are you sure those specific packages (or their dependencies) actually install a service?

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those packages install [service](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/x11vnc/filelist) [files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/xvfb/filelist) for you to use. To run these programs as daemons on startup, you will need to create the systemd unit files yourself.

Here are some instructions for x11vnc: https://askubuntu.com/a/676978/797559

Here are instructions for xvfb: https://superuser.com/a/912648/910217

Comment: Thank you so very very much.. It occurred to me a few hours after posting that (very roughly speaking) maybe not all application packages which you might think of as services don't in fact install a "service" in systemd terms. You learn something new every day. I used 20.04 a lot and had a quite complex setup that did what I outlined I wanted to do above and I can certainly say that I never had to create systemd unit files myself. Anyway, thanks once again for your quuick concise on-point reply. Now I can get busy again!